# Indices solving for $x$

Tags: arithmetic, exponentiation

Sorry this is a simple question but I'm having difficulty with it .

$$2(16^{3x+2}) = 1 / 8^{5x-4}$$

I'm told to solve for $x$.

My working -

$$2(16^{3x+2}) = 1 / 8^{5x-4}$$

$$32^{3x+2} = 8^{-5x+4}$$

$$32^{3x+2} = 8^{-5x+4}$$

$$(2^5)^{3x+2} = 2^{3(-5x+4)}$$

$$5(3x+2) = 3(-5x+4)$$

$$15x + 10 = -15x + 12$$

$$30x = 2$$

$$x= 1/15$$

My answer is wrong .. Can I get some help or hint on where did I go wrong ?

Comment: Please correct the tag to Arithmetic (or Algebra, but not Linear Algebra). Also please try to learn MathJax so that your posts are better read.

Comment: Formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: You computed $2(16^{3x+2})$ as $32^{3x+2}$, but it is your mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$2\cdot16^{3x+2}=\dfrac1{8^{5x-4}} \iff2^{1+4(3x+2)}=2^{-3(5x-4)}$$

$$\implies1+4(3x+2)=-3(5x-4)\iff x=?$$